# Why does this template argument deduction fail on GCC but not Clang?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++20, template-argument-deduction

I'm using Clang and GCC trunk with `-std=c++20` and the following code compiles fine on Clang but fails on GCC.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <climits>
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>
#include <immintrin.h>

#define VECTOR_SIZE 32

template <typename T> requires std::is_arithmetic_v<T>
using vec __attribute__((__vector_size__(VECTOR_SIZE))) = T;

template <std::unsigned_integral T>
constexpr vec<T> rotl(vec<T> x, int k)
{
    constexpr auto N = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(T);
    return (x << k) | (x >> (N - k));
}

template <std::unsigned_integral T>
constexpr vec<T> rotr(vec<T> x, int k)
{
    constexpr auto N = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(T);
    return (x >> k) | (x << (N - k));
}

vec<uint32_t> test(vec<uint32_t> x)
{
    return rotr(x, 7);
}
```

GCC error:

```
x86-64 gcc (trunk) (Editor #1, Compiler #1) C++#1 with x86-64 gcc (trunk)
<source>: In function 'vec<unsigned int> test(vec<unsigned int>)':
<source>:27:20: error: no matching function for call to 'rotr(vec<unsigned int>&, int)'
27 |         return rotr(x, 7);
    |                ~~~~^~~~~~
<source>:19:22: note: candidate: 'template<class T>  requires  unsigned_integral<T> constexpr vec<T> rotr(vec<T>, int)'
19 |     constexpr vec<T> rotr(vec<T> x, int k)
    |                      ^~~~
<source>:19:22: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:19:22: note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from <source>:3:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20210524/include/c++/12.0.0/concepts: In substitution of 'template<class T>  requires  unsigned_integral<T> constexpr vec<T> rotr(vec<T>, int) [with T = __vector(8) unsigned int]':
<source>:27:20:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20210524/include/c++/12.0.0/concepts:102:13:   required for the satisfaction of 'integral<_Tp>' [with _Tp = __vector(8) unsigned int]
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20210524/include/c++/12.0.0/concepts:108:13:   required for the satisfaction of 'unsigned_integral<T>' [with T = __vector(8) unsigned int]
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20210524/include/c++/12.0.0/concepts:102:24: note: the expression 'is_integral_v<_Tp> [with _Tp = __vector(8) unsigned int]' evaluated to 'false'
102 |     concept integral = is_integral_v<_Tp>;
    |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In function 'vec<unsigned int> test(vec<unsigned int>)':
<source>:27:20: error: no matching function for call to 'rotr(vec<unsigned int>&, int)'
27 |         return rotr(x, 7);
    |                ~~~~^~~~~~
<source>:19:22: note: candidate: 'template<class T>  requires  unsigned_integral<T> constexpr vec<T> rotr(vec<T>, int)'
19 |     constexpr vec<T> rotr(vec<T> x, int k)
    |                      ^~~~
<source>:19:22: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:19:22: note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from <source>:3:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20210524/include/c++/12.0.0/concepts: In substitution of 'template<class T>  requires  unsigned_integral<T> constexpr vec<T> rotr(vec<T>, int) [with T = __vector(8) unsigned int]':
<source>:27:20:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20210524/include/c++/12.0.0/concepts:102:13:   required for the satisfaction of 'integral<_Tp>' [with _Tp = __vector(8) unsigned int]
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20210524/include/c++/12.0.0/concepts:108:13:   required for the satisfaction of 'unsigned_integral<T>' [with T = __vector(8) unsigned int]
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20210524/include/c++/12.0.0/concepts:102:24: note: the expression 'is_integral_v<_Tp> [with _Tp = __vector(8) unsigned int]' evaluated to 'false'
102 |     concept integral = is_integral_v<_Tp>;
    |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it to be a **GCC bug in the template-argument-deducation resulting from your alias in combination with the vector intrinsics attribute** as:

- It compiles if you [**specify the template argument of `rotr`**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vGN77umUmZM9bbUw) manually.
- A simplified example without concepts in C++17 also compiles on [Clang and Intel compiler but yet again fails on GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/K6MKWThT1). Therefore C++20 `concepts` can't be the reason!
- It compiles fine if you only exchange the alias with a simple [**`struct vec`**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OoUUyqxwdfbebmAo).

So the code itself without template-argument-deduction seems to be perfectly valid just somehow GCC ends up deducting `T = __vector(8) unsigned int` which then fails the `std::unsigned_integral<T>` concept as `is_integral_v<T>` evaluates to `false`.

I guess for a better answer that explains you why this might happen you will need a `language-lawyer`.

Comment: Yes, it does look that way. If gnu.org ever allows me to reset my password I plan to submit this as a bug.

Comment: Another thing I have noted is that if you put a general `Cont<T>` as a `template template` then this [Clang will fail as well](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Zh9Tr2RLsPoxOwu1) but again this works for a `struct` or an alias for `std::vector` in both compilers. So the bug (?) seems to be related to the way you define your alias. It is actually the first time I see somebody using a templated alias for `__attribute__((__vector_size__()))`. So far I have only seen people `typedef` it without a template parameter...

Comment: @Chris_F So actually I think you could make your example more minimal by removing concepts, replacing `VECTOR_SIZE` with `32` and removing the body of the functions as well as `rotl` entirely.

Comment: Bug submitted. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100766

Comment: @Chris_F Perfect, I'll keep also track of it. I have had the opportunity to briefly have a look at the standard and it says that an alias template is as deductible as the underlying type. Therefore the problem seems to boil down to [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NVUgx5rosCNjHtdc). GCC fails at deducting a templated vector intrinsic while Clang succeeds with the template deduction.

Comment: @Chris_F Seems somebody read it and posted it faster than us. At least that person agrees that it is a bug as well.